# How to write russian in default.po in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I try the following code in locale of cakephp for smooth translations.

locale/rum/lc_messages/default.po

```
msgid  "welcome"                             

msgstr "ишь, я уже пишу по-русски, н"
```

.ctp code

```
<?php __(welcome); ?>
```

I am getting lots of ??????????????
in place of the above text.

Comment: You need to make sure your file is saved as UTF8.

Comment: Don't edit the .po files by hand. Use Poedit or some other specialized program.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need to make sure you are saving as UTF-8 without BOM markers.

You also need to change the character encoding CakePHP will set on the page. See app/core.php